# Breaking my head to get Url Routing in IIS 7 hosting environment : ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I am trying to implement ASP.NET URL routing using the **System.Web.Routing**. And this seems to work fine on my localhost however when I go live I am getting an IIS 7's 404 error (File not found). FYI the hosting uses Windows Server 2008 IIS7.

I think this is making some difference in handling the routing mechanism. But I am not able to figure out whats exactly happening. Below are the settings and changes that I've made so far to get it work and to give some credit to myself it works absolutely fine locally.

**Web.Config Settings**

And then I have a system.webserver section that has the following markup

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
               type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
                   System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, 
                   Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>   

</system.webServer>
```

Then in the Application_Start section I have defined one route as follows:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{               
    routes.Add(
       "MyRoute",
          new Route("ProductDetail/{ProductId}/{ProductName}",
                new MyRouteHandler("~/ProductDetail.aspx")));
}
```

Finally MyRouteHandler looks as follows:

```
 public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
 {
     var display = (Page)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                     _virtualPath, typeof(Page));
     HttpContext.Current.Items["ProductId"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["Product"]; 
     return display;
 }
```

And on the routed page I am grabbing the product ID as follows

```
ProductId = (int)HttpContext.Current.Items["Product"];
```

And this is the end of my mess. And this works fine locally. I have been trying this for a while but didn't succeeded so far.

ANY HELP WILL BE DEEPLY APPRECIATED.

Thanks...

Comment: do you have any rewrite rules implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you were able to figure out what the problem was...however if you are still looking for a solution then you may try the following. I had to face the same situation some time back and got it to work using Rewrite rules in Web config for which you will not need any routing mechanism. So first I would encourage you to remove any routing setting you may have and the code from the Global.asax file too.

Then in the  section you can add as rewrite rules as follows

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="map1" defaultValue="(.+)"/>
    </rewriteMaps>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for map1">
        <match url="product/(.+)/(.+)"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{map1:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="productdetail.aspx?Product={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

If you have problems understanding the rewrite mechanism I would recommend that you read [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) by Scott Guthrie.

I think this should work for you given a IIS 7.0 or 7.5 environment.

Comment: yup I figured the issue long time back and did fixed it using rewrite maps itself...anyways thanks for your response

Comment: user153410, I have same issue. Can u suggest how did u fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I followed this article:
[How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx)

Before I found it I had issues on my shared host and none locally.  It was my web.config.

My host was using IIS 7 with Integrated Pipeline, I was  missing this:

```
<handlers>
    <!---after all the others--->       
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*"
             path="UrlRouting.axd"
             type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler,
             System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
             Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

EDIT:  According to your settings and code, the only thing left is to check to see if you have the Routing dll defined in web.config and also deployed to your bin directory:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can you tell what changes you made to your web.config. That would be really helpful.

Comment: I added what fixed my problem.  The article is very clear on how to set up Routing based on the host settings.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for the reply. I have everything in the Web.Config and i have looked at the article you suggested. How ever I have all the necessary settings in Web.Config. I am really not able to figure out why its doing this. I dont know why IIS 7 is so complicated in getting simple things like this as URl routing or rewriting is very common these days.

Comment: thanks, was missing urlroutinghandler - saved me a head ache friend

Answer (score 3):

Try this in you web.config. Worked for me.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: After uploading website form local dev to webhost, was getting 404 on routing. runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to inform what was finally my solution... on the IIS7 change the pipeline mode to Integrated and I folowed adding some lines on the web.config from the link above...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx

good luck.