# 404 error found in URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I have implemented The UR routing in my projects,it works fine on my local machine,
But gives 404 error on the server, In IIS there is Application Pool is Asp.net 2.0

I have added the below line in my Web.config:

```
 <add name="RoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
  System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't publish some code, but I guess you refer to virtual path on your dev machine, and in the server it's a regular application (in IIS) so it doubles your path:

D:\webhome\ **Transtutors-May\Transtutors-May\** Questions\finance

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of handling this situation:
 [Breaking my head to get Url Routing in IIS 7 hosting environment : ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608035/312718)